# Running into error for google translation of data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, translation

I am attempting to translate a list of tweets with the following sample code:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator  
translator = google_translator()  
translate_text = translator.translate('สวัสดีจีน', lang_src='th',lang_tgt='en')  
print(translate_text)
```

I keep running into the following long error when I run the code:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_trans_new\google_trans_new.py in translate(self, text, lang_tgt, lang_src, pronounce)
    188                         raise e
--> 189             r.raise_for_status()
    190         except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    940         if http_error_msg:
--> 941             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    942 

HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://translate.google.cn/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute&q=EgRrvwCgGLHwuIAGIhkA8aeDS9RXYOujcLlE7r1EY3pCFB3PU57xMgFy

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

google_new_transError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e0a80cf9e6cc> in <module>
      1 from google_trans_new import google_translator
      2 translator = google_translator()
----> 3 translate_text = translator.translate('สวัสดีจีน', lang_src='th',lang_tgt='en')
      4 print(translate_text)
      5 #output: Hello china

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_trans_new\google_trans_new.py in translate(self, text, lang_tgt, lang_src, pronounce)
    192         except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    193             # Request successful, bad response
--> 194             raise google_new_transError(tts=self, response=r)
    195         except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    196             # Request failed

google_new_transError: 429 (Too Many Requests) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown
```

Is this because I have used the translator too frequently? When will it reset so I can continue my work?

Comment: The returned response will include an HTTP Header `Retry-after`. This means you will also need to add `try/except` code to handler exceptions.

Comment: What do you expect from the unofficial API?... (besides, asking for how Google rate-limit users is absolutely not-answerable on this site.)

Comment: @JohnHanley would you mind providing an example of what you mean? I am a usual R user and do not have much experience with try/except

Comment: Google search for a Python tutorial on exception handling. Then print out the response headers to see the `retry-after` value.

Comment: Since this is an unofficial API, there is a high possibility that your IP was blocked if you processed too many request. This was confirmed by the creator of [google_trans_new](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/24#issuecomment-755973296).

Answer (score 0):

[google_trans_new](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) is an unofficial library using the web API of [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com) and also is not associated with Google.
It is crawling the translate web page, which is why you eventually received a 429 error message which is the **HTTP 429 Too Many Request** status code.
These kind of unofficial libraries are unstable and will eventually get blocked.

To get a stable application you should use the [official library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-translate/) which calls the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).
The Cloud Translation API has [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas) but it takes care of handling these errors with retries using [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Cloud Translation is available as a paid service`, so you won't be able to submit many translation requests either.